# Get entity property with Spring JPA

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa

I'm using Spring JPA in my DAO layer. I have an entity `Projet` having inside an entity property `Client`:

**Project.java**

```
@Entity
public class Project {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int projetId;

    private String libelle;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="client_id")
    private Client client;

    // ... constructors, getters & setters
}
```

**Client.java**

```
@Entity
public class Client {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int clientId;

    private String denomination;

    // ... constructors, getters & setters
}
```

in my DAO interface I have the following specifications:

**ProjetDao.java**

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public interface ProjetDao extends CrudRepository<Projet, Integer> {

    @Transactional
    public Projet findByLibelle(String libelle);

    @Transactional
    public Projet findByProjetId(int projetId);
}
```

***My question is:*** How can I specify in my DAO interface a method that will return all clients distinct in `List<Client>`?

Comment: try to use a method that return a List<Client>

Comment: Yes exactly, I want to return List<Client>

Comment: @MohamedRedaArherbi I gave you the example in the answer with the reference to the documentation

Comment: Just as a note, there are tools that will work more smoothly if you just use `id` as the name of the ID property (Spring Data's `Identifiable` interface, for one), and you can just use the built-in `findOne` method on the repository interface.

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-creation) and [JIRA](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-680):

```
 List<Project> findAllDistinctBy();
```

> The query builder mechanism built into Spring Data repository infrastructure is useful for building constraining queries over entities of the repository. The mechanism strips the prefixes find…By, read…By, query…By, count…By, and get…By from the method and starts parsing the rest of it. The introducing clause can contain further expressions such as a Distinct to set a distinct flag on the query to be created. However, the first By acts as delimiter to indicate the start of the actual criteria. At a very basic level you can define conditions on entity properties and concatenate them with And and Or.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I want to have all the clients distinct without parameters for the selection.

Comment: findAllDistinct

Comment: Sorry didn't work, it shows me the error `No property findAllDistinct found for type Project!`. The method that I wrote in my Dao is `public List<Client> findAllDistinct(); `

Comment: You can add a client DAO with such method.

Comment: Yes I know, but I'm searching a way to do it on the table Project, this is the aim.

Comment: @MohamedRedaArherbi I've found the solution I believe. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are dealing with a one-to-one relationship, in this case I guess the list that you need is not really related to specific project, you just want a distinct list of clients.
You will need to create another repository (ClientRepository) for the Client entity and add a findAllDistinct method in this repository.